# Using repeating Notifications using AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I'm trying to develop an app which requires scheduled notifications everyday at 7am, 11am and 7pm. And when user taps on the notification it takes the user to MainActivity.

I have a working code but it's showing random behavior. I have the following problems.

1) Every time I open MainActivity, it triggers the alarm manager and shows a notification even though it's only supposed to be triggered at 7am, 11am and 7pm.

2) Also, I think I'm somehow duplicating alarms every time I open the main activity. Everytime I setup the alarm, I cancel the pending intent and then setup again. Is this the correct way to do it?

**Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
    notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

    PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, 0);
    PendingIntent broadcast1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 101, notificationIntent, 0);
    PendingIntent broadcast2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 102, notificationIntent, 0);

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    alarmManager.cancel(broadcast);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, broadcast);

    cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    alarmManager.cancel(broadcast1);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, broadcast1);

    cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
    cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    alarmManager.cancel(broadcast2);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, broadcast2);
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String Text = getText();

    Resources res = context.getResources();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    Notification notification = builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_notify)
            .setTicker("Ticker")
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText(Text)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11355325/2900127)

Comment: give shared prefernces varibale time instead of AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY means when you trigger 7am setrepeat interval 4 hours then when it trigger 11am change that varibale interval time to 8hours(difernces between 11am and 7 pm) so like this.It may work